# building an nxn matrix in python numpy, for any n

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Is it possible using numpy for python (versions 3.3) to write the code for building an nxn matrix, without specifying n? I need to index the entries as A_i,j or something like that, but I dont even know how to define the A_i,j so that they are actually objects. I thought something like this might work:

```
n    
i=1
j=1

when i (is less than) n+1

  when j (is less than) i+1
   A_i,j= f(i,j)
   j+=1

i+=1
```

but this does not work...any suggestions?
My ultimate Goal is to write the QR decomposition for an arbitrary nxn matrix. But I need to know how to define the matrix that I am working on first. I am very new to python and thus numpy and so dont know much of anything. any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also new to stackexchange so sorry for the bad piece of code i have there. (is less than) is supposed to  mean the triangle sign missing the base with head pointing to the left- that is the obvious less than symbol

Comment: Look at the `shape` property of the numpy array

Answer (score 4):

You can create an empty `n`x`n` array:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

my_array = np.empty([n, n])
```

Then set the value at coordinate `i, j` to `f(i, j)`.

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(n), range(n)):
    my_array[i, j] = f(i, j)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply this is great. I still can't get it to work however. i get an error at the line containing my_array saying that 'module' object has no attribute 'fromfunction'. does this mean that my numpy program does not know where to find the fromfunction? do i need to download or install some file containing it? thanks again.

Comment: @user3495725 I have edited my answer, no longer using `fromfunction`